# Mobile Payment SDK for IOS/Android ?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, payment-gateway

I am making an application for Android and IOS and this application is having a Mobile Payment. But actually this is a donation To any firm with NonProfit reasons. I am looking for some Mobile Payment That support the both platform. I tried to read the Paypal but i don't found any donation button in there SDK.I also checked out the some question over here and i Found apple support the third party payment gateway only for the physical goods and for virtual things i must go on with IAP. But they deduct the 30% of the amount. I want any alternative that i can go with minimum usage charges and payment for Donation (I think that is also a virtual payment). 
Can any one provide me some idea to go in to a direction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can start with PayPay SDK. It's supporting both iOS as well Android.

If you are doing payment for Donation, then I hope, apple will not reject your app.

Below is helpful url for it.

```
https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile

https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-2532
```

Cheers and Enjoy with starting!